# WebAssembly: Accessing COM Objects

Tags: com, webassembly

I would like to access a COM interface from a WebAssembly module. If possible, this will be my first WebAssembly module. Can it be done? What challenges and/or restrictions might I face when accessing a COM interface from WebAssembly?

Comment: No, WebAssembly itself do not have low-level hardware APIs

Comment: @Haden Pike - Are you asking about accessing the serial-port?

Comment: @Jackdaw I was asking about the Windows Component Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly is more or less like a virtual machine, one can't communicate directly with any other parts of the system if the needed interfaces aren't implemented or provided for the virtual machine. WebAssembly won't provide such thing for you, thus, you (or some project probably doesn't exist yet) have to do more work to make such thing happen.